# What is the breakdown voltage of the following?

Tags: high-voltage, electricity

I actually have multiple questions and I decided it would be more efficient if I were to ask a question with multiple questions attached.

#### Background

I’m an experimenter that now has a new project in mind. I call it the 10,000 project when really it should be called the 25,000 project. I’m using 4 microwave oven transformers (MOTs) with a voltage doubler circuit using high voltage capacitors.

I am attempting to make a high voltage supply that has an input of almost 100 amps.

So besides my point let’s get right to my questions.

#### Questions:

1. What is the breakdown voltage of the typical magnet wire insulation in a microwave oven transformer?
2. What is the breakdown voltage of vegetable oil?
3. What is the breakdown voltage of PVC tubing with a thickness and air gap of 1 cm?

Please, if you or someone else has any knowledge you or they would like to share given experience or knowledge I would greatly appreciate it.

Note: the frequency is 60-50 Hz

Further Notes: Yes I know the size of capacitor I need.
No it won't output 100 amps, sorry for the typo. It should be fixed. it uses 100 amps. My shop has a 200 amp breaker switch. With 48,000 watts and 240 volts 3 phase access.

Thanks

Comment: Consider this:   Your primary coil will draw much more current than the secondary.  It goes up approximately as the windings ratio.  Take a smaller step and consider getting 1100VAC at 100A from 110VAC.  That's a ratio of 10.  You will have to provide 1000A at 110VAC.  Where are you planning on getting that amount of current?

Comment: BTW:  The amount of power and energy you are considering should scare you spitless.  If it doesn't, then you really shouldn't be fooling with this.

Comment: Plus, are you really trying to make a 60 Hz voltage doubler that puts out 100 amps? Do you have any faint idea how BIG your capacitors will have to be?

Comment: To answer your questions. Yes I know the dangers and capacitor sizes I need.